# How can I control all of these situations that I want to find no reservation at that selected checkin and checkout time?

Tags: c#, linq

I have implemented a hotel booking system but I have a problem with controlling the available times of the room.

There is a foreach loop to control each room one by one. And I have wrote this code below. But in the date of the searching available room for example let say Room1 has a reservation at checking time 28.05.2021 and checkout time is 14.08.2021. And a customer come to the system and he search a available room at time 17.07.2021 checkin time and checkout time is 24.07.2021. So, here is the problem the system says that the Room1 is available at that time. But the Room1 is not available. How can I control all of these situations that I want to find no reservation at that selected checkin and checout time. My code is below.

```
List<Rooms> availableRooms = new List<Rooms>();
foreach(var item in db.Rooms){
   var reservationList = item.Reservations.Where(x =>
         (x.CheckInTime.Value.AddDays(1) >= checkinTime && x.CheckInTime.Value.AddDays(1) <= checkoutTime) ||
          (x.CheckOutTime.Value <= checkoutTime && x.CheckOutTime.Value >= checkinTime)).ToList();

   if(reservationList.Count() == 0 || reservationList == null)
         availableRooms.Add(item);
}
```

I also .AddDays(1) because the customer can arrive at 10.00 AM to the room and the customer must leave at 16.00 PM.
What is the best solution for this algorithm?

Comment: You're saying checkin time is 17.07.2021 - is that the exact value of your DateTime object?  A DateTime is generally midnight by default, unless you specify otherwise. So you need to make sure you have the exact checkin/checkout times (not just dates) specified on your variables. That should make your algorithm much easier, without a need to add additional days to try to make your comparisons work.

Comment: Okey then how can I implement to control these times and days?

Comment: Why do you name you variables `CheckInTime` and `CheckOutTime` when they are actually `CheckInDate` and `CheckOutDate`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two overlapping cases: the new reservation can overlap the existing reservation by checkin or checkout, so if a room has any reservation where the new checkin time is between the reservation, or the new checkout time is between the reservation, it is a conflict.

```
var availableRooms = db.Rooms.Where(room => !room.Reservations.Any(r => (r.CheckInTime.Value <= checkinTime && checkinTime <= r.CheckOutTime.Value) ||
                                                                        (r.CheckInTime.Value <= checkoutTime && checkoutTime <= r.CheckOutTime.Value)))
                             .ToList();
```